# how to make a header fit the page limits

Tags: html, css, header, border, padding

I have this simple code:

```css
body {
    padding: 0;
    background-color: red;
    margin: 0;
}

header {
    background-color: blue;
    text-align: center;
  }
```

```html
<body>
    <header>
        <h2>Vendi su eBay e guadagna extra cash!</h2>
    </header>
</body>
```

The problem is that the header is still not at the top of the page and every solution I found isn't working, what's wrong?

[image: here is a screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
h2 {
 margin: 0;
}
```

h2 tag has the default margin so just make it 0.

Answer (score 1):

It's because margin of h2.

```css
body {
    padding: 0;
    background-color: red;
    margin: 0;
}

header {
    background-color: blue;
    display:flex;
    justify-content: center;
    
}
```

```html
<body>
    <header>
        <h2>Vendi su eBay e guadagna extra cash!</h2>
    </header>
</body>
```

Comment: Ok, it works, but is there any way i can set the h2 margin to 0 without having to give it an id? Like if there is any way to do that by styling the header

Comment: then add like this. ``header h2{margin:0}``

Comment: I edited my answer. Do you mean like that?